# Divide one array in two table view cell

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview

I have an array, let's call it list

```
var list = ["name1", "name2", "name3", "name4", "name5"]
```

I have two prototype cells, the first one should have the first index of array  in its title and the second should should has the rest

In both cells, I wrote `indexPath.row`, could anyone help me to how to divide this array to use in both cells.

In another word, I want to have 5 cell in my table view

cell 1 with Identifier: "list1" should have these items in its title = ["name1", "name2", "name3"]

cell 2 with Identifier: "list2" should have these items in its title = [ "name4", "name5"]

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return list.count
    }

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "list1", for: indexPath) as? ListCell {
        cell.list1Title?.text = list[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    } else if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "list2", for: indexPath) as? ListCell {
        cell.list2Title?.text = list[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
    return TableViewCell()
}
```

Comment: Show your other data source methods (numberOfSections and numberOfRowsInSection).

Comment: Do you want 5 rows to appear in the table view, one for each entry in the array (using list1 for the first and list2 for the other 4)? Or do you want 2 rows to appear in the table view (list1 for the first and list2 for the 2nd showing all four remaining values in the one row)?

Comment: Your question now has conflicting information. First you state *"the first one should have the first index of array in its title and the second should should has the rest"* but then you write the first cell should be used with the first three items and the second cell should be used with the last two. Which way do you want it? Please fix your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want 5 rows to appear in the table view, the following will show the first three values using cell "list1" and the remaining values using cell "list2":

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.row < 3 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "list1", for: indexPath) as! ListCell
        cell.list1Title?.text = list[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    } else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "list2", for: indexPath) as! ListCell
        cell.list2Title?.text = list[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}
```

Of course this assumes your `ListCell` has both `list1Title` and `list2Title` properties. Normally you would actually have two different cell classes for the two types which means you use two different casts instead of casting both to `ListCell`.